# Per-month or per-minute billing of Azure Devops Pipelines parallel jobs

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My question is, are the number of parallel DevOps jobs charged per-second, per-minute, or only per month?

Especially when evaluating setups (we're in the process of migrating from a TeamCity rig), we try different configurations of cloud-hosted vs self-hosted agents, and compare performance vs maintenance work and pricing.

So, say we use 15 cloud-hosted build agents for a week, and then 15 on-prem ones the next week, and then scale back to 2-3 of each for the rest of the month, will we be charged a full month for both 15 on-prem and 15 cloud agents, or do you divide the charge in sub-months, so that we could get charged for 1/4 of a month for each of the 15 on-prem and cloud-hosted agents?

It's difficult to tell from the documentation. Azure Support told me on Twitter to ask in the MSDN forums, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/263527/per-month-or-per-minute-billing-of-azure-devops-pi.html

But, then I found this answer, which says that DevOps is no longer suppoerted on there: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/72cfd507-06a9-4a43-82d5-58b1eb48df56/azure-devops-pipelines-pricing-and-usage-running-on-deployment-groups?forum=AzureStack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We tested this because we need more deployment agents for 1-2 days once per month. We use Microsoft Hosted agents and they are charged per day. So we did increase the number of agents in the middle of the day and decreased back the next day and the increased charge happened for 2 days which was verified on the billing costs in Azure:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/billing/billing-faq?view=azure-devops#q-how-much-am-i-currently-spending-on-azure-devops

If you want to verify this yourself, this shows up in Azure > Cost Management > Cost Analysis.
And filter over Service Name: Azure Devops.

Comment: Looks like MS does agree, see the reply here:

https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/t/per-month-or-per-minute-billing-of-azure-devops-pi/1333337#T-N1334598